# How do I change date format in SQL SELECT?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I want to change the date format in my SQL calling, but I got the wrong output how to solve this?

```
SELECT s.id, format(s.TransacDate,'dddd, d MMMM, yyyy') AS formatDate, s.name
FROM sales s
JOIN user u
ON s.No = u.No
WHERE u.logId= 'abcde';
```

[OUTPUT DATE THAT I GET FROM THE QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZVv4.png)

This is how my DB store the format date `2020-10-21 09:25:10`

I want to achieve the result of `21/10/2020 09:25:10`

How do I fix my current query in order to achieve the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that "format" is the MSSQL function. For MySQL, try [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
date_format(s.TransacDate, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be correct answer.

```
SELECT s.id, format(s.TransacDate.getdate(),'dd/MM/yyyy,hh:mm:ss') AS formatDate, s.name
FROM sales s                             //  --------------------
JOIN user u                               //           ^--------------------- change here
ON s.No = u.No
WHERE u.logId= 'abcde';
```